# How to change svn user without checking out fresh copy

Tags: linux, svn, centos6

I am trying to change svn user.
I was using svn with username "ABC" now due to some name conflict my username is changed to "ABC.1"
How can I change username from "ABC" to "ABC.1", but I don't want to checkout a fresh svn copy.
Just need to change user only.
I am using "svn +ssh" protocol and using Cent-OS 6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command if you are using svn+ssh protocol:

`svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://currentUser@server/path  svn+ssh:/newUser@server/path`

it works fine on CentOS

Comment: Downvoted because `svn switch --relocate` has been deprecated for years. Use `svn relocate` instead: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#svn-relocate

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`relocate`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html) (assuming you have svn 1.7 or newer):

```
svn relocate svn+ssh://currentUser@server/path svn+ssh://newUser@server/path
```

Or `switch` if you are still at svn 1.6:

```
svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://currentUser@server/path svn+ssh://newUser@server/path
```

Answer (score 1):

Pradip's and krzyk's answers won't work in case you use HTTP(S). You will have to remove the [cached credentials](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds) instead of relocating.